# How do I get the Script Manager selection to display under the Tools menu item in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm new to google sheets and scripts and have been trying some of the tutorial on extending sheets.  I've noticed that the tutorial demo Sheets have a Script Manager selection under the Tools menu.  When I create my own Sheets and related scripts and function, however, I do not get a Manage Scripts selection in the Tools menu.

Why is this?  How do I get the Manage Scripts selection in the Tools menu?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This menu item was in the old version of spreadsheets, it disappeared in the new version you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That's a shame I'm rather fond of it and wish it were in the new version.  Thanks again.